# Please help me code javascript with content tab div?

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
function change(){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "text </br>"; //
}
</script>
<div id="test"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="change()" value="Change content">
```

but when I execute code, it does not display data.
Thank you all!
I had try it but result no change. I think seem properties not support data into contain tabs HTML: 
...

Comment: close script tag properly otherwise this should works see http://jsfiddle.net/737BY/1/

Comment: The `language` attribute has been deprecated. You can omit the `language` and the `type` attribute since HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing `<script>` tag. That is the problem.

```
<script>
function change(){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "text </br>";
}
</script> <!-- it should be closing tag -->
<div id="test"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="change();" value="Change content">
```

Better to remove `language` attribute because now in HTML5 it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<input type="button" onclick="change();" value="Change content">
```

and change Script to `</script>`

Answer (score 0):

See, It works...

```
<script language="javascript">
function change(){
     document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "text </br>"; //
}
</script>
<div id="test"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="change()" value="Change content">
```

[image]

You just need to review your code before running.

Comment: How is this useful? There are two other answers that state exactly the same.